# Puppet manifest has a file declaration that somehow duplicates itself

Tags: puppet

Given the confusing error message:

> err: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on
>   SERVER: Duplicate declaration: File[/etc/logstash/conf.d] is already
>   declared in file 
>   /var/lib/puppet/envs/SYS_15378/modules/logstash/manifests/config.pp at
>   line 54; cannot redeclare at
>   /var/lib/puppet/envs/SYS_15378/modules/logstash/manifests/config.pp:54
>   on node foo.bar.com

Questions:

- If this is really duplicating a file, how do I go about debugging it (finding the file)?
- If not... what is this actually communicating?

Notice:

- the duplicate declaration is on line 54
- the file it is duplicating is defined on... line 54
- line 54 is the same line as line 54

The line in question is the closing brace of:

```
file { "${logstash::params::config_dir}":
   ensure  => directory,
   owner   => root,
   group   => root,
   mode    => '0755',
   purge   => true,
}
```

where

```
class logstash::params {
 $config_dir = '/etc/logstash/conf.d'
  ...
}
```

Comment: Am I right to assume that this piece of code is from inside a defined type?

Comment: That is correct, it's inside `define logstash::config(...) {`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Defined types should not declare common resources, meaning such that are not derived from the `define` instances `$name`.

In your example, the directory is a resource that many instances of your `define` need. It should therefor move to a (perhaps dedicated) class.

```
class logstash::config_dir {
    file { "${logstash::params::config_dir}":
        ensure  => directory,
        owner   => root,
        group   => root,
        mode    => '0755',
        purge   => true,
    }
}
```

In your `define`, you just

```
include logstash::config_dir
```

Including a class multiple times poses no problem and solves exactly that problem (among others).

Answer (score 1):

This probably means that you're including the file twice. Do you include the logstash module twice anywhere? It's possible that you're meaning to include it twice, but with different config dirs. If you're accidentally including it twice with the same config dir, then you'll get the error.

Comment: I'll check that and trace through some more dependencies

Comment: No. Classes can be `include`d an arbitrary number of times. Their singleton aspect ensures that no duplicate resource declaration will result.

Answer (score 0):

If you copy an existing file within your manifests directory to another name (for reference purposes) but keep the ".pp" suffix, Puppet will try to include it again and will complain about the duplication. Try renaming to ".pp_OLD"

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same kind of issue when I used create_resource().

This error occurs when you want to run 'file{}' block several times like a loop.

When we are creating a multiple copies of a 'file{}' block, we have to make sure that the NAME OF THE FILE BLOCK is unique, i.e.,

file { "NAME OF THE FILE BLOCK":.....}

If the same name repeats, the above error is raised.

In your case, some value of "${logstash::params::config_dir}" must have been repeated twice.