# Puppet: Duplicate delcaration on same line when using `define`

Tags: node.js, npm, puppet

Trying to get some NPM packages installed both locally and globally. I am doing it like this:

```
$npm_packages_loc = {
    'mysql' => {
        'version' => 'latest',
        'ensure'  => 'present',
    },
    'googleapis' => {
        'version' => 'latest',
        'ensure'  => 'present',
    }
}
```

This simply says that I want the 'mysql' and 'googleapi' packages installed, and I want them at the latest version.

```
## Install NPM local packages
# Obtains and multiplexes NPM packages defgined in '$npm_modules_loc'
define npm_packages($version, $ensure) {
    npm_packages_loc_inst { $version:
        package => $name,
        ensure  => $ensure, 
    }
}
# Installs the packages via nodejs::npm
define npm_packages_loc_inst($package, $ensure) {
    $version = name
    nodejs::npm { "/opt/app/:${package}":
        ensure  => $ensure,
        version => $version,
    }
}
create_resources ('npm_packages', $npm_packages_loc)
```

However, when doing a puppet run I get the following error:

**Duplicate declaration: myapp::Npm_packages_loc_inst[latest] is already declared in file /etc/puppet/modules/test/myapp/manifests/init.pp:79; cannot redeclare at /etc/puppet/modules/test/myapp/manifests/init.pp:79**

Not sure why it is behaving like this, but I am obviously doing something wrong. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25858390/puppet-manifest-has-a-file-declaration-that-somehow-duplicates-itself

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. It was because of this line:

```
npm_packages_loc_inst { $version:
```

As both 'versions' were set to 'latest', it thought there was a duplicate declaration (**Npm_packages_loc_inst[latest]**). Changing this to 'name' fixed the issue:

```
npm_packages_loc_inst { $name:
```

Now looks like:

**Npm_packages_loc_inst[googleapis]** \
**Npm_packages_loc_inst[mysql]**

Hence no duplicate declaration. Hope that helps other people out there.

Comment: Really weird that Puppet doesn't tell you where the duplicate declaration actually IS . . . just gives you the same line number twice.