# Puppet: Duplicate declaration issue

Tags: puppet

I am trying to create a base directory structure on agent instances. Also, i have a `define` function for copying files to agent node.

```
[tom@pe-server] cat site.pp
node 'my_node' {
    include base::create_dir

    util::copy_files { 'Copying jar files':
        source      => 'puppet:///modules/java',
        destination => 'c:/java_dump/test',
        copy_all    => 'yes',
    }
}


[tom@pe-server] cat copy_files.pp
define util::copy_files ($src, $dest, $copy_all = '') {
    if ($copy_all == 'yes') {
        file { $dest:
            ensure       => directory,
            source       => $src,
            sourceselect => all,
            recurse      => true,
        }
    } elsif {...}
}


[tom@pe-server] cat create_dir.pp
class base::create_dir (
    $dir_list = $base::params::dir_list,
) inherits base::params {
    $dir_list.each |$dir| {
        file { $dir:
            ensure => directory,
        }
    }
}


[tom@pe-server] cat params.pp
$dir_list = [
    'c:/java_dump',
    'c:/java_dump/test',
],
```

When applying changes on agent, i get the following error:

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: {"message":"Server Error: 
Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating 
a Resource Statement, Duplicate declaration: File[c:/java_dump/test] is already declared in file /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/automation/modules/base/manifests/create_dir.pp:5; cannot redeclare at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/automation/modules/util/manifests/copy_files.pp:17 at 
/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/automation/modules/util/manifests/copy_files.pp:17:9 at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/automation/manifests/site.pp:79 on node my_node"
```

While searching online, i came across this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25858390/puppet-manifest-has-a-file-declaration-that-somehow-duplicates-itself). The link states moving *common resource* to a `class` and include that class in `define`. I'm not sure why is that needed and how to implement it. I did the following changes:

```
define util::copy ($source, $destination, $copy_all = '') {
    include util::copy_files
}
```

Also replaced `util::copy_files` with `util::copy` in site.pp

Error i am now getting is:

```
Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call, Class[Util::Copy_files]:\n  expects a value for
parameter 'src'\n  expects a value for parameter 'dest' at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/automation/modules/util/manifest
s/copy.pp:2:5 at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/automation/manifests/site.pp:79 on node my_node
```

Comment: That answer you linked to is for a different kind of issue. Anyway, creating directories from an array doesn't really need its own defined type since that is an intrinsic. Removing that define should help you to improve this design with refactoring and remove that error.

Comment: Oh, i thought it was related to that issue. BTW, i am not using a defined type for creating directories. As shown above, i've just created a manifest for dir creation so i could include it whenever required. This manifest creates a set of dirs that are required on each host, hence a manifest was created. Also, as shown above, i've created a `defined` type for copying files and directories. With these details in place, how can i overcome this duplicate declaration issue?

Comment: Yeah i combined those in my head for some reason. The solution is still going to be refactoring.

Comment: Ok. What confuses me though is that both are doing different tasks altogether. One is just creating a fixed directory structure and another (copy_files) will be used for copying stuff into any of the directories created above. While copying anything into any of the directories, one has to ensure that the directory should be present. I'm sure i'm not the only one to get into this situation.

Comment: The thing is, your `copy_files` is also creating the directory and defining its nested structure with the files being copied over, so both are creating the directory structure. This is why the `purge` and `force` attributes also exist for recursive directory creation.

Comment: Overall, this seems pretty simple to understand.  It must be the case that the value bound to class parameter `$base::create_dir::dir_list` either is or contains the value `'c:/java_dump/test'`.  As a result, the iteration in class `base::create_dir` produces a declaration of `File[c:/java_dump/test]`.  Given the parameters with which it is invoked, your instance of `util::copy_files` also declares `File[c:/java_dump/test]`.  The combination of these constitutes a disallowed duplicate declaration of that resource.

Comment: Yes, i understand that but here's the case: i want to enforce a consistent directory structure on the agent nodes which i'm achieving using `create_dir` manifest. All entries present there are required. Now any of our Puppet code (scripts/config files) that needs to be copied on agent should go into one of the dirs created above. How do i achieve that?